# Insert innormation to new row in DF using another csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Df containing a `start_year` coulmn and another csv containing `year` and `population`

How can I insert the values of the population into my Df in new column, using this csv? Exemple:

DF :

```
start_year:
400
405
410
412
```

Population csv :

| Year | Population |
| --- | --- |
| 399 | 5 |
| 400 | 6 |
| 404 | 20 |
| 409 | 30 |
| 410 | 31 |

Desierd DF:

| start_year | population |
| --- | --- |
| 400 | 6 |
| 405 | 20 |
| 410 | 31 |
| 412 | 31 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `pd.merge_asof()` method:

```
#Population=pd.read_csv('Population.csv') 
#df=pd.DataFrame({'start_year':[400,405,410,412]})

out=pd.merge_asof(df,Population,left_on='start_year',right_on='Year').drop('Year',1)
```

output of `out`:

```
    start_year  Population
0   400         6
1   405         20
2   410         31
3   412         31
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, below code might do your task.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], columns=["start_year"])

pop=[]
with open("file.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    for r in csv_reader:
        pop.append(r[1])

csv_file.close()

df['population'] = pop

print(df)
```

I have tested the code for csv file containing below data
1,100
2,200
3,300
4,400
5,500

And it outputs following dataframe

```
   start_year population
0           1        100
1           2        300
2           3        300
3           4        400
4           5        500
```